# Scanner - parsing code values using delimiter regex

Tags: java, regex, int, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to use a Scanner to read in lines of code from a string of the form "p.addPoint(x,y);"

The regex format I'm after is:

`*anything*.addPoint(*spaces or nothing*` OR `,*spaces or nothing*`

What I've tried so far isn't working: `[[.]+\\.addPoint(&&[\\s]*[,[\\s]*]]`

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `[...]` defines a character class, and what you have so far is totally broken.  Research the meaning of brackets in regex and try again.

Comment: I'm confused about the _spaces or nothing_. Only spaces and nothing else? Aren't you trying to catch numeric values?

Comment: This is the delimiter regex, basically what passes as a separator between the integers.

Comment: [.+\\.addPoint(\\s*[,\\s*]] doesn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested this in Python, but the regexp should be transferable to Java:

```
>>> regex = '(\w+\.addPoint\(\s*|\s*,\s*|\s*\)\s*)'
>>> re.split(regex, 'poly.addPoint(3, 7)')
['', 'poly.addPoint(', '3', ', ', '7', ')', '']
```

Your regexp seems seriously malformed. Even if it wasn't, matching infinitely many repetitions of the `.` wildcard character at the beginning of the string would probably result in huge swaths of text matching that aren't actually relevant/desired.

Edit: Misunderstood the original spec., current regexp should be correct.

Comment: doesn't seem to be working...

my input is "poly.addPoint(3, 7); //#5" Note, it's supposed to receive both the 3 and the 7.

Comment: What output are you getting for that input, and what output do you desire? More specifically, are you trying to split the string at the match? Are you trying to group the numerical arguments and extract them? More details please.

Comment: Using the regex as the Scanner delimiter, I'm trying to use while(hasNextInt()) and grab both the 3 and 7 as integers using nextInt(); twice. Does that make sense? 

I'm not getting any output from your regex.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that particular class, but take a look at whether the current version of the regexp seems to do what you need.

Comment: what does the | mean in this case?

Comment: It's essentially an `or` type of operator. It means it will attempt to match against each of the regexps separated by the `|` character one-by-one until a match occurs or all the alternatives have been exhausted.

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
public class MyPattern {

    private static final Pattern ADD_POINT;
    static {
        String varName = "[\\p{Alnum}_]++";
        String argVal = "([\\p{Alnum}_\\p{Space}]++)";
        String regex = "(" + varName + ")\\.addPoint\\(" + 
                argVal + "," + 
                argVal + "\\);";
        ADD_POINT = Pattern.compile(regex);
        System.out.println("The Pattern is: " + ADD_POINT.pattern());
    }

    public void findIt(String filename) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(new FileReader(filename));

        while (s.findWithinHorizon(ADD_POINT, 0) != null) {
            final MatchResult m = s.match();
            System.out.println(m.group(0));
            System.out.println("   arg1=" + m.group(2).trim());
            System.out.println("   arg2=" + m.group(3).trim());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        MyPattern p = new MyPattern();
        final String fname = "addPoint.txt";
        p.findIt(fname);
    }

}
```